# What is the URL scheme for google home app on ios?

Tags: ios, google-maps, url, google-home

I want to launch google home app from my own app but what Url scheme do I need to open google home app ?

Comment: google actions. it is an extension of google now api

Comment: No, to open google map app from other ios app you use googlemaps:// so is there similar url scheme for google home?